# apostrophe as dead key prints apostrophe before special character

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, keyboard, google-chrome

Since this morning i have strange bug. I have apostrophe as dead key for latvian characters. Everything was fine untill this morning. Now when i hit apostrophe and, for exapmple "a", i get "'ā" instead of "ā". How can i fix it?

I have this bug on Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 14.04, most likely after update i did after turning pc on.

I tried to remove "Latvian (Apostrophe variant)" and adding it back, but no change. I restarted pc hoping it was just a glich, but still no luck.

Please help.

Comment: I little correction. I just noticed that this bug is only in Chrome. Still no luck fixing it :(

Comment: same here. first time i faced the problem few months ago after upgrading to ubuntu 14 and installing chromium. All was fine in chrome, so i used that till now. Just updated system and chrome started to do this too, looks like chrome merged chromiums latest code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Ubuntu problem. I am working on Fedora and have exact same problem.

Chromium is at fault this time.
And unfortunately there is no fix for this at the moment.
All we can do is follow open ticket on chromium issue board : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375670
 or use alternative input mothod (like, Alt key)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to chromium issue board. i will follow that.